# How to change text on click with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

This is the code I want to make work. When I click button everything remains the same.

`Console.log` does change though. What is wrong? Thanks

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import ExpenseDate from './ExpenseDate';
import Card from '../UI/Card';
import './ExpenseItem.css';

function ExpenseItem(props) {

const [title, setTitle]= useState(props.title);

const clickHandler=()=>{

    setTitle('Updated!');
    console.log(title);
};

    return (
    
    <Card className='expense-item'>
        
          <ExpenseDate date={props.date}></ExpenseDate>      
  
        <div className='expense-item__description'>
            <h2>{props.title}</h2>
            <div className='expense-item__price'>${props.amount}</div>
        </div>
        <button onClick={clickHandler}>Change title</button> 
    </Card>
    );
}

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Comment: you have `<h2>{props.title}</h2>` rendered while on click you are updating the internal title state. just replace that with `<h2>{title}</h2>`

Comment: In your h2 you want to put {title} and not {props.title} -> title is the state and changes, props.title is a prop and changes only if the parent changes

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `props.title` instead of `title` in your HTML. Even though your state value is updating, you are not using this value. Instead, you are using the initial value passed by your component props.

Answer (score 2):

Although there has been an answer already, I thought i'd make things a bit more clear here, from a wider point of view.

Say you have `ComponentA` which provides a title to `ComponentB` via props:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    return <ComponentB title={"Test"} />
}

const ComponentB = (props) => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState(props.title)
    return <h1>{props.title}</h1>
}
```

Here what you are essentially doing is telling `ComponentB` to take its initial state from `props.title`, but during the lifecycle of the component, you are changing `title`, however, in the `h1` tag you are still rendering `props.title` and not `title` which is the title in your state.

To get around this, you can do 2 things: render `title` instead of `props.title` in your `h1`, or [lift the state](https://react.dev/learn/sharing-state-between-components#lifting-state-up-by-example) to `ComponentA` in order to have a more clear and strict control of what the UI renders:

```
const ComponentA = () => {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("some title")

    return (
        <ComponentB 
            title={title}
            setTitle={setTitle}
        />
    )
}

const ComponentB = ({title, setTitle}) => {

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <input value={title} onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

This way, you only have one title, which gets rid of the confusion. In most cases, reducing the number of variables is a good practice as long as it serves to simplify the code and it does not interfere with other things in your application.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your code. As pointed out, you are using wrong variable to print the data.

`<h2>{props.title}</h2>` to `<h2>{title}</h2>`

Answer (score -1):

In react, the main difference between state and props is that state is mutable while props is not. So if you want to update the value you must use local state instead of props.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like you are rendering the props instead of the state. Rather than `<h2>{props.title}</h2>` please retry with `<h2>{title}</h2>`